# "Merging" Core Data Models

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

Since its kinda hard to explain I'm gonna example it:

Let's say Model V1 has an entity called Names, which in its first version has only a property called name; in the second version of the model, now Model V2, it also has lastName property. Since the new model schema has both name and lastName properties in it, it won't accept any SQLite(?) or Model without those properties. So what I want is try to merge the Model V1 into Model V2 matching fields according to MappingModels or any other kind of migration.

So my question is, can I do what I just explained or do I need to iterate over all Model V1 properties and manually match them to the newest properties on the current model?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with [lightweight migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1). Very simple, no code necessary.

Another issue is how you are going to deal with the data that's already there. I presume it is a string that contains both first and last names. You would have to devise an algorithm that separates first from last and modifies the new fields. In this case you would indeed have to iterate through the data. But the particulars of this would be suitable for another question.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question at all or I didn't explain it very well ... The thing is, I already versioned models, what I'm trying to do is restoring data from Model V1 and merge it into Model V2 with the SQLite file of Model V1. I don't know if there's a way to merge data through different SQLite files with different DB Schema